# For which power of a matrix does it has eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-theory

I Have the following question in my exercise:

Let $T:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$

$[T]_E= \left[ \begin{matrix} 2&-4\\5&-2\\\end{matrix} \right]$

The question asks to find all $n \in \Bbb N$ so that $T^n$ has a non-trivial invariant subspace.

I Understand that since $\dim(V)=2$ the invariant subspaces which are not trivial (not $\{0\}$ or $\Bbb R^2$) must be of $\dim=1$ and thus be the Eigenvectors of $[T^n]_E$ but I don't get how am I suppose to know for which $n$ the eigenvectors exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : If you have $Ax=\lambda x$ for some eigenvector $x$, you also have
$A^n x=\lambda^n x$

Comment: Yeah but I find that $|\lambda I - A| = \lambda^2 + 16$ so there is no solution for $n=1$ and i don't see how I can find the general $A^n$

Comment: You can use the complex solutions $4i$ and $-4i$. From this, it follows, that $A^2$ has eigenvalue $-16$. Or simply calculate the eigenvalue of $A^2$, then you have solved at least the case $n$ even.

Comment: Oh, so I'm allowed to use complex solutions in order to find the real ones! nice, thanks!